# Failed i3wm install package has unment dependinces

Tags: installation, apt, software-center, i3-wm

Tried installing i3wm from these instructions using the Ubuntu ppa http://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html

Got this error when I typed in the final command apt-get install i3

```
sudo apt-get install i3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 i3 : Depends: i3-wm (= 4.6.1-1+g4.6-88-ge99158e1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I tried downloading the .deb file and running it I get an error in the software center saying

"Dependency is not satisfiable: i3-wm (=4.5.1-2)

Any ideas I am pretty much a noob

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- sudo apt-get install i3-wm
- sudo apt-get install i3status

Also, you will find this helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Installation
If you're going to be getting into i3, the arch wiki is very helpful.

If that doesn't work, try downloading the .deb for i3-wm (as i3-wm is the dependency which you are having trouble with for some reason).

Comment: I got the same error for i3-wm but i3status installed sucessfully. I tried running the .deb again but got the same error. Will look over the wiki now.

Comment: It can't be an identical error for i3-wm; i3-wm can't be a dependency for itself. Can you copy the error code you're getting?